# How do I search this site from my phone?

Tags: support, android-browser

I can type into the search box, but I can't seem to get it to submit. When I click the Enter or OK buttons it just seems to change focus to another field.

Similarly, I can't figure out how to close the messaging bar at the top of the screen. I can't scroll far enough to the right to close it.

Not sure if it matters, but this is with a Motorola Flipside running 2.1.

Comment: I just tried to edit the question to post some screenshots but the image upload overlay was also an exercise in frustration that ended in disappointment.

Comment: The issues you're seeing are, of course, endemic to the whole Stack Exchange network, not just this site. You may wish to post about them on the "[Mother Ship](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)", as that's where the Stack Exchange team will more likely be found. I'm sure they want to hear about how the sites work (or not, in this case) with a mobile browser.

Comment: Hard to say whether they'll care, though, since it mostly works on the 2.2 browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't even bother with the search function here. While they've recently improved it, Google (and even other web searches) are still far superior.

`site:android.stackexchange.com searchterm` in your Android/Google search field should find you what you need.

As for the other issues, this site isn't optimized for mobile browsers (seems like a no-brainer to me) so that there are "wonky" things with the interface doesn't surprise me, nor do I think they'll be a high priority. However, someone has created a mobile-optimized "proxy" for the Stack Exchange network, called Stack Mobile. You might try that and see if that works better for you.

http://stackmobile.com/site.php?site=android.stackexchange

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll go with google using the "site:" option. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're seeing the same as we used to see on Galaxy S's when they were running 2.1, see this question on the main site:

[How to use the Search box on these Stack Exchange sites with the Galaxy S?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/how-to-use-the-search-box-on-these-stack-exchange-sites-with-the-galaxy-s)

Comment: Thanks, that does sound like the same issue. Any tips on how to remove the messaging bar along the top of the site?